# What worldwide topographical etymology dictionaries exist?

Tags: toponomastics, toponyms

What worldwide topographical etymology dictionaries exist?

Comment: You've used a French word. It's topographical in English...Also, please explain more fully what you mean.

Comment: France has a: Dictionnaire topographique de la France.

Comment: I have seen many for the British Isles, but the famous one (England only) is *The Concise Oxford Dictionary of English Place-names* by Eilert Ekwall (four editions: 1936, 1940, 1947, 1960)